# How do I get my ajax key/values to be recognized in the "params" object in a controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I'm trying to send some data via JQuery ajax to a grails controller

Here's the data

```
var data =
                     {'status':"SOMETHING",
                      'scheduleDate':remindDate.toString("MMMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss tt"),
                      'dueDate':parsedDate.toString("MMMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss tt"),
                      'owner':"SOMETHING ELSE",
                      'type':'concierge',                                   
                      'notes':"NOTES",
                      'party': "SOME PARTY VALUE"
                    };
```

...and here's the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/concierge/todo/add',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function(x) {
                        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                          x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                        }
                      },

                    success: function(result) {
                        refreshMyUI(null);
                    }
                });
        });
```

I can get this working if I don't POST the data but use a GET. But if I post, the data comes in like this:

```
[{"status":"do","scheduleDate":"February 06 2011 3:26:07 PM","dueDate":"February 06 2011 3:26:07 PM","owner":"3","type":"concierge","notes":"hoooo","party":"3"}:, action:add, controller:todo]
```

This is the value of "params" when the controller is called. Note that my parameters are not merged propertly with the other parameters; it's as if the entire string is a "key" on the LHS of the colon, and there's nothing on the other side.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the hypen in `application/j-son` intentional or a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `JSON.stringify` and have just `data: data`